# Does Storm support temporal relationships between events?

Tags: apache-storm, complex-event-processing, temporal

I am looking for a way to detect events that did not happen. Example: Event B should happen within 15 minutes of event A. Esper has “time:interval” and Drools Fusion has “window:time” and “After”.

Answer (score 0):

No Storm cannot do this out of the box. You would need to write your own code and put that into a Storm bolt, for which you can possibly utilize Storm tick tuples.

Storm is distributed and fault-tolerant realtime computation system and as such it does not do complex event processing.

CEP tools such as Esper and Drools can analyze a series of events for patterns like the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you.  I would really like to use Drools but cannot find an HA solution. There is support for persistent sessions but it appears they are limited to save all/retrieve all, e.g. no ability to efficiently add and remove single events like hibernate would add/remove a single record from a DB. This would be expensive for a large, long running data set (STREAM mode) Persistent sessions is a partial solution and I am unclear how we would even operate a cold/warm/hot standby. I like your idea of using storm tick tuples, but don’t like to lose all the native temporal options in fusion.